# npm command is not being recognized in terminal

Tags: npm, spawn, enoent

```
PS E:\github search project\github> npx create-react-app
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe"
npm ERR! path E:\github search project\github
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent spawn C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe" ENOENT
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-08-02T15_35_10_969Z-debug-0.log
PS E:\github search project\github>
```

This is the error I am getting. I tried everything like changing path, changing comspec but nothing works. What is the problem?